# Gaussian correlation inequality for triangles

Tags: probability, integration, normal-distribution, correlation

The Gaussian correlation inequality was recently proved for centrally symmetric convex sets. For example it applies to a circle and a rectangle, but not to a circle and a triangle centered at 0.

Is the statement actually false for circle and triangle?

Sorry, I'm not familiar with integrating Gauss distributions, otherwise I could check myself.